Use variable date (has dashes) to match an expression that is void of dashes
I am using exported variables saved in .bashrc that are dates for today and the next day to try to find matches for them in a webpage that I'm scraping for weather info. I had to save the date variables with separators (which are dashes) otherwise I couldn't export them to ~/.bashrc which a script updates automatically. The problem is that the dates I am trying to match them to from the webpage have spaces and the origin dates have dashes.
An example of an exported variable I have in ~/.bashrc:
export xdate=Fri-04-Oct

So if I try to match to Fri 04 Oct as it shows up on the webpage like this:
grep -F $(echo $xdate | tr '-' ' ')  casablanca_info

My result only matches on Fri which is why I used -F to try to match the whole string. I am new to programming and I know that I can use grep like grep -F 'Fri 04 Oct' without a hiccup but I can't match on the string when its in a variable and I remove the spaces.
I also tried to wrap $xdate in quotes like this
grep -F $(echo "$xdate" | tr '-' ' ')  casablanca_info

and I have tried changing it from how its saved in ~/.bashrc to
export xdate='Fri-04-Oct'

to force searching for the whole string including spaces and I am back to only returning Fri in my result.
The advice I received from shellcheck.net suggested to put quotes around $xdate or to include a shebang directive which I tried just for giggles but I have been testing this directly in the bash shell, to get it to work before storing the code in a script.

It seems an exceedingly bad idea to use your .bashrc as the storage for application data, especially automatically written data.  If something goes wrong then it could break your environment, perhaps even to the extent that you can no longer log in.  I urge you to put the data in a different file.

Will do thanks. In my learning... nevermind that makes perfect sense.

exported variables should be all upper case, e.g. export XDATE instead of export xdate, see correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization.

shellcheck would have told you to to put quotes around $xdate and to include a shebang directive, not or.

You need to put the command substitution in quotes so it will be a single argument:
grep -F "$(echo $xdate | tr '-' ' ')" casablanca_info

There's also no need to use command substitution, you can use the shell's built-in character replacement operation:
grep -F "${xdate//-/ }" casablanca_info

You could just store the date with spaces in the variable, as long as you quote it:
xdate='Fri 04 Oct'
grep -F "$xdate" casablanca_info

In general you should always quote variables and command substitutions, unless you specifically need to perform word splitting and globbing on the result.
